# jquery, how to use nextAll() with css scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class="my_1"></div>

<div class="my_big">     
      <div class="small" id="id_1"></div>      
      <div class="small" id="id_2"></div>     
      <div class="small" id="id_3"></div>      
      <div class="small" id="id_4"></div>      
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var css_scope=$(".my_big");
var next_div=$(".my_1").nextAll('.small',css_scope).first();

console.log(" \n next div = "+ next_div.attr('id'));
```

console shows `undefined`. But if I exclude the `my_big` div  from html and define `var next_div` in javascript as follows:

`var next_div=$(".my_1").nextAll('.small').first();`,

expected output is obtained.

How to make `nextAll()` work with the mentioned css scoping ?

Comment: `.nextAll` is just not the right function for this, since it considers only siblings. Why not `$('.my_1 + .my_big').children('.small').first()` OR `$('#id_1')`? `.nextAll` only accepts one argument btw.

Comment: What is your problem? You're just not using nextAll() the right way! http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: did you wrap your code with `$(function() {CODE});` ?

Comment: @PulkitMittal, `nextAll()` should be duscarded here ?

Comment: No, its not about discarding. There are multiple ways of accessing the elements, the question is which elements particularly do you want to access. Post your full HTML for that.

Comment: @PulkitMittal, wanna access the first div inside `my_big` div.

Answer (score 0):

`.nextAll` is used to find all the next siblings, you should find the `.small` from the result of `nextAll`.

```
var next_div=$(".my_1").nextAll('.my_big').find('.small').first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* get to `.small` from `my_1` using `nextAll()` since they are not siblings. You can get to it using the following selector.

```
// Get the first element matching ".small" inside an element matching ".my_big"
// that comes immediately after an element matching ".my_1"

var next_div = $('.my_1 + .my_big > .small:first')​;
```

Check this **demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/q6XKR/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the first element in `my_big` div, there's no need to bring `my_1` into the scene.

```
var next_div = $('.my_big').find('.small').first();

console.log(" \n next div = "+ next_div.attr('id'));
```

Hope it clarifies you somewhat about traversing elements in jQuery.